# COM object becomes null after two calls

Tags: c#, com

I'm loading COM DLL in my c# project. It normally works, but 3 times in the past couple of weeks, the COM object "becomes" null.

What's strange is the object is used in two lines just before where it "becomes" null.

```
var comType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("MyDllLibrary");

var abc = Activator.CreateInstance(comType);

var first = "first";
var second = "second";

//comType is not null and works fine
comType.InvokeMember("First", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, abc, new object[] { first });
comType.InvokeMember("Second", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, abc, new object[] { second });

string data = "data";

//comType becomes null here...
//ERROR: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
var workedData = comType.InvokeMember("DoWork", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, abc, new object[] { data });
```

This happens seemingly randomly and very infrequently. I can't reproduce it. 
Any idea why this happens and how to prevent it?

Comment: Are you sure that it isn't the called COM component that triggers the error?

Comment: Off-topic suggestion: If you want your code to look a little less cryptic, you could either (a) define COM interop types for that COM component (using `[ComImport]` etc.) or (b) use the `dynamic` keyword (late binding), instead of calling into your COM component using Reflection (`Activator.CreateInstance`, `type.InvokeMember`, etc.).

Comment: As @stakx says. Can you run the 'First' several times without issue, the 'Second' several times, then finally 'DoWork'. If it always fails when hitting the 'DoWork' it would appear that the error could be inside the COM Dll's method. Finally, if 'DoWork' is returning null from it's method legitimately, this will also cause an error - you can't initialise a 'var' with null...

Comment: Re: _"This happens seemingly randomly and very infrequently"_, here's two somewhat far-fetched ideas. (1) The object might get released during garbage collection. If so, adding `GC.Collect()` statements at various points in the above code might make the problem reproducible. (2) There might be a difference between debug and release builds. The compiler and JIT compiler only perform some optimizations (such as statement reordering) in release builds.

Comment: This is a bit of a bug in the CLR, it does not distinguish well enough between an NRE generated by managed code vs an AVE from native code.  The underlying reason is otherwise the same, your COM server has a bug and dereferences a null pointer.  Of course you can't get help with it here, use a telephone.

Comment: For those who like me were wondering what NRE and AVE means, I guess "NRE" = `NullReferenceException` and "AVE" = `AccessViolationException`.

Comment: @stakx That would seem more likely (the COM component triggering the error). Although the input for the DoWork method should accept any string. I tried a null and empty string and they worked fine. 
I also tried called 'GC.Collect()' directly above the DoWork line...still no error.

Comment: What does 'DoWork' return?

Comment: @StevePadmore DoWork returns a string (technically a type 'object' though)

Comment: Could this 'object' be null sometimes? If so you will get the error trying to assign the result to the 'var'. It will need to be strongly named to allow for a null return.

Comment: @StevePadmore to be honest, I don't know if the object it returns could be null. It's a super old DLL. If that were the error though, would the fix to just change 'var workedData' to be 'string workedData'?

Comment: I would think so - worth a try...